# как сохранить состояние виджета switch, используя shared preference, на flutter?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, switch, flutter, dart

Есть класс ChangeTheme, на котором есть виджет switch, который меняет тему приложения, но если перейти на другой экран, а затем вновь вернуться на на экран со switch, то он будет вновь не активен. Так же, если закрыть приложение, то установленная тема switch'ом сбрасывается. Как исправить это?

ChangeTheme.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:todo/theme.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';



class ChangeTheme extends StatefulWidget{

  ChangeTheme({Key key, this.title}): super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  MyState createState() => new MyState ();

}


class MyState extends State<ChangeTheme>{
  bool val = false;
  String message = "смена темы";
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    set();
    return new Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Настройки'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
               new Switch(
                 value: val,
                 onChanged: (bool e) => setState(() => something(e)),
                ),
                new Text (message),

                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

 void something(bool e) {
   ThemeChanger _themeChanger = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    setState(() {

      if (e){
        _themeChanger.setTheme(ThemeData.dark());
        message = "Темнаяя тема";
        val = e;
        get();

      } else {
        _themeChanger.setTheme(ThemeData.light());
        message = "Светлая тема";
        val = e;
        get();
      }
    });
 }
  get() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final myBool = prefs.getBool('my_bool_key') ?? false;
  }
  set() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('my_bool_key', true);
  }

}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'theme.dart';
import 'ChangeTheme.dart';
import 'Constants.dart';

void main() async => runApp(new TodoApp());

class TodoApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
      builder: (_) => ThemeChanger(ThemeData.light()),
      child: new MaterialAppWithTheme (
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new TodoList(),
      theme: theme.getTheme(),
    );
  }

}

class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new TodoListState();
}

class TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {

  List<String> _todoItems = [];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getPrefs();
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Список задач'),
      actions: <Widget>[
      PopupMenuButton<String>(
       onSelected: choiceAction ,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context){
         return Constants.choices.map((String choice){
            return PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: choice,
              child: Text(choice),
            );
         }).toList();
        },
      )
      ]),
      body: _buildTodoList(),

      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _addTodoItem,
          tooltip: 'Add task',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTodoList() {
    return new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < _todoItems.length) {
        return _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index], index);
      }
    });
  }


 void choiceAction(String choice){
    if (choice == Constants.ChangeTheme){
      _changeTheme();


    }

    else if (choice == Constants.OffAd){
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Хочешь отключить рекламу?\n\n'
                    'Разработчку и дизайнеру тоже хочеца кушатб, '
                    'поэтому для отключения рекламы отправь деняк. '),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('подробнее'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('нет я жмот'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                ]);
          });


    } else if (choice == Constants.info){
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Todo\n'
                                'Разбработчик:  \n'
                                'Дизайнер:  \n'
                                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('оценить'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('отмена'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                ]);
          });

    }
 }

 void _changeTheme(){
   Navigator.push(context,
       new MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => new ChangeTheme()));
 }



  Widget _buildTodoItem(String todoText, int index) {
    return new ListTile(
        title: new Text(todoText), onTap: () => _removeTodoItem(index));
  }

  void _addTodoItem() {
    // Push this page onto the stack
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('добавление задачи')),
          body: new TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            onSubmitted: (val) {
              _addItem(val);
              Navigator.pop(context); // Close the add todo screen
            },
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Введите вашу задачу',
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
          ));
    }));
  }

  void _addItem(String task) {
    if (task.length > 0) {
      setState(() => _todoItems.add(task));
      _setPrefs();
    }
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text('Задача "${_todoItems[index]}" выполнена?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('отмена'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('выполнена'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _removeItem(index);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    })
              ]);
        });
  }

  void _removeItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _todoItems.removeAt(index));
    _setPrefs();
  }

  void _setPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList('TodoList', _todoItems);
  }

  void _getPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getStringList('TodoList') != null)
      _todoItems = prefs.getStringList('TodoList');
  }

}
```

theme.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeChanger with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;

  ThemeChanger(this._themeData);

  getTheme() => _themeData;
  setTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    _themeData = theme;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Constants.dart

```
 class Constants {
  static const String ChangeTheme = 'Настройки';
  static const String info = 'Информация';
  static const String OffAd = 'Отключить рекламу';

  static const List<String> choices = <String>[
    ChangeTheme,
    info,
    OffAd
  ];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заменил `something` на `onThemeChanged`, подправил `main` чтобы считывались настройки с `SharedPreferences`. И добавил мелкие исправления чтобы все заработало. Не совсем понял для чего `get()` и `set()` в `ChangeTheme.dart`, не стал трогать.

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    var darkModeOn = prefs.getBool('darkMode') ?? true;
    runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
        builder: (_) =>
            ThemeChanger(darkModeOn ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light()),
        child: MaterialAppWithTheme(),
      ),
    );
  });
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new TodoList(),
      theme: theme.getTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new TodoListState();
}

class TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  List<String> _todoItems = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getPrefs();
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Список задач'), actions: <Widget>[
        PopupMenuButton<String>(
          onSelected: choiceAction,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Constants.choices.map((String choice) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        )
      ]),
      body: _buildTodoList(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _addTodoItem,
          tooltip: 'Add task',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTodoList() {
    return new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < _todoItems.length) {
        return _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index], index);
      }
    });
  }

  void choiceAction(String choice) {
    if (choice == Constants.ChangeTheme) {
      _changeTheme();
    } else if (choice == Constants.OffAd) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Хочешь отключить рекламу?\n\n'
                    'Разработчку и дизайнеру тоже хочеца кушатб, '
                    'поэтому для отключения рекламы отправь деняк. '),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('подробнее'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('нет я жмот'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                ]);
          });
    } else if (choice == Constants.info) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Todo\n'
                    'Разбработчик:  \n'
                    'Дизайнер:  \n'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('оценить'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text('отмена'),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                ]);
          });
    }
  }

  void _changeTheme() {
    Navigator.push(context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ChangeTheme()));
  }

  Widget _buildTodoItem(String todoText, int index) {
    return new ListTile(
        title: new Text(todoText), onTap: () => _removeTodoItem(index));
  }

  void _addTodoItem() {
    // Push this page onto the stack
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('добавление задачи')),
          body: new TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            onSubmitted: (val) {
              _addItem(val);
              Navigator.pop(context); // Close the add todo screen
            },
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Введите вашу задачу',
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
          ));
    }));
  }

  void _addItem(String task) {
    if (task.length > 0) {
      setState(() => _todoItems.add(task));
      _setPrefs();
    }
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text('Задача "${_todoItems[index]}" выполнена?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('отмена'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
                new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('выполнена'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _removeItem(index);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    })
              ]);
        });
  }

  void _removeItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _todoItems.removeAt(index));
    _setPrefs();
  }

  void _setPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList('TodoList', _todoItems);
  }

  void _getPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getStringList('TodoList') != null)
      _todoItems = prefs.getStringList('TodoList');
  }
}
```

ChangeTheme.dart

```
class ChangeTheme extends StatefulWidget {
  ChangeTheme({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  MyState createState() => new MyState();
}

class MyState extends State<ChangeTheme> {
  var _darkTheme = true;
  String message = "смена темы";
  // FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    set();

    final themeChanger = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    _darkTheme = (themeChanger.getTheme() == ThemeData.dark());
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Настройки'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Switch(
              value: _darkTheme,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _darkTheme = val;
                });
                onThemeChanged(val, themeChanger);
              },
            ),
            new Text(message),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onThemeChanged(bool value, ThemeChanger themeChanger) async {
    (value)
        ? themeChanger.setTheme(ThemeData.dark())
        : themeChanger.setTheme(ThemeData.light());
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('darkMode', value);
  }

  get() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final myBool = prefs.getBool('my_bool_key') ?? false;
  }

  set() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('my_bool_key', true);
  }
}
```

theme.dart

```
class ThemeChanger with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;

  ThemeChanger(this._themeData);

  getTheme() => _themeData;

  setTheme(ThemeData themeData) async {
    _themeData = themeData;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

UPD: Также можно [создать свои темы](https://rxlabz.github.io/panache_web/#/) и использовть их. Пример:

```
final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
  primaryColor: Colors.black,
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF212121),
  accentColor: Colors.white,
  accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
  dividerColor: Colors.black12,
);
```

И вместо `ThemeData.dark()` использовать `darkTheme`.

Comment: MiT ты везде)) просто красавчик

Comment: @ДенисАкулов я один из немногих, кто отвечает на вопросы по Flutter и Dart))